# Spring XD on YARN: ver 1.2.1 direct binding support for kafka source

Tags: spring-xd

Spring XD on YARN: ver 1.2.1 direct binding support  for kafka source.

1.I know this is not supported yet(as of ver 1.3.0), any definite date/ver would help our project schedule ?

2.This direct binding for kafka source support is very critical for our project. We are in a situation to totally abandon Spring XD YARN in our project just because of this.

Trying to do

stream create --name directkafkatohdfs --definition "kafka | hdfs"
stream deploy directkafkatohdfs --properties "module.*.count=0"

Hitting the exception "must be a positive number. 0-count kafka sources are not currently supported"

I just want to eliminate the use of message bus/transport(redis/kafka/rabbitMQ) and want to have a direct binding of source(kafka) and sink(sink) in the same YARN container.

1.I know this is not supported yet(as of ver 1.3.0), any definite date/ver would help our project schedule.

2.This direct binding for kafka source support is very critical for our project. We are in a situation to totally abandon Spring XD YARN in our project just because of this.

Thanks
Satish Srinivasan
satsrinister@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the interest in Spring XD :).

For Spring XD 1.x, we suggest using composition instead of direct binding with the Kafka bus - or, in your case, the Kafka source. However, apart from that, in Spring XD 1.x it is not possible to create an entire stream without at least one hop over the bus (regardless of the type of bus or modules being used).

We are addressing direct binding (including support for entire directly bound streams) as part of Spring Cloud Data Flow (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) - which is the next evolution of Spring XD. We are intending to support it as a specific configuration option, rather than as a side-effect of zero-count modules. From an end-user perspective, SCDF supports the same DSL as Spring XD (with minor variations) and has the same administration UI, and definitely supports YARN, so it should be a fairly seamless transition. I would suggest starting to take a look at that. The upcoming 1.0.0.M2 release of Spring Cloud Data Flow will not support direct binding via DSL yet, but the intent is to support it in the final release which is currently planned for Q1 2016.